# How to create mini game admob ads

Tags: admob

recently I'm encountering new type of ads, which work like mini games (for example Mobile Strike ad, which is tower defence mini game). I cannot find any hint how to implement something like this and what framework (I guess it'll be html5 based) I have to use.

Any help would be appreciated,
Regards

Answer (score 1):

i guess you're speaking about playable ads, there was a cool article on ironsrc about that format, check it http://www.ironsrc.com/news/what-are-playable-ads/ i think that might be useful. 
as i understand that format differs from standard banners/interstitials/video ads that are served by ad providers. the point is that playable ads are mostly used in direct ad campaigns, for instance, when you promote one of your games in another. To implement them you need html5 and afterwards you can add to your campaign. Here's a nice explanation of key differences by dude from mNectar:

> HTML5 and App Stream Playables. Both types have their strong suits -
>   but generally an App Stream Playable is product marketing where the
>   actual app/game is streamed and a user can play before installing.
>   HTML5 Playables are great where killer app / hook moments are created
>   to have the user interact and engage before making an install
>   decision. The core commonality is that user engagement is required
>   before installing, which helps find the right content match for users
>   and developers.
>
> Fundamentally, HTML5 Playables are a great entry point for the ad
>   format as a vast improvement over traditional mobile ads that don't
>   engage pre-install, such as Video or Interstitial.
>
> Blockquote

here's that ^^^ thread with similar question on quora https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-ad-networks-that-have-HTML5-playable-game-ads-in-their-portfolio-of-ad-types

to sum up i think you just need to create a direct campaign through admob or other ad network or mediator (i think this option is better) -> create creatives for playable ads -> download the creatives to your campaign and check the results. hope this might help